# Generalize Scala filter

Tags: scala

How can this filter be amended to include `ignoreExtensions` :

```
  val ignoreExtensions = List("css", "js")        //> ignoreExtensions  : List[String] = List(css, js)
  val links = List("test.css", "file.html")       //> links  : List[String] = List(test.css, file.html)

  links.filter(f => !f.endsWith(".css"))           //> res0: List[String] = List(file.html)
```

Currently it works by hard coding ".css" into the filter, but would like to filter remove any items that end with any elements in List ignoreExtensions ?

Comment: Shouldn't `test.css` be filtered out?

Comment: @m-z your right, question updated. Could also use filterNot I geuss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
links.filterNot(f => ignoredExtensions.exists(ext => f.endsWith(ext)))
```

Comment: as per m-z suggestion I've edited your code to use : "  links.filterNot(f => ignoreExtensions.exists(ext => f.endsWith(ext)))" but answer is yours, thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can do it as following.

```scala
links.filter(f => ignoreExtensions.contains(f.dropWhile(_ != '.').drop(1)))
```

Answer (score -2):

A for comprehension will return a `List[List[String]]` so I added a call to `flatMap` at the end to, well, flatten it, into a `List[String]`.

```
( for ( ext <- ignoreExtensions ) 
  yield ( links.filter(_.endsWith(ext)) ) 
).flatMap(x=>x)
```